# Getting Stream from Facebook page with neosmart

Tags: facebook, stream

Im using neosmart jquery plugin to get streams from facebook to my own page.

The plugin requires the page id from the fanpage, and mostly its working ok.

But with the link https://www.facebook.com/midtfynsgymnasium i cant get anything.

I guess the page id is 121130641250864 but i cant get the data. Is it because they have put on a "noread" attribute ?

Comment: There is no page_id of 121130641250864, and https://www.facebook.com/midtfynsgymnasium in unreachable... Can you post a working link to the page?

Comment: if you view the source code of https://www.facebook.com/midtfynsgymnasium

Comment: As I said above - that URL is unreachable  - possibly to people that are not administrators of that page...

Comment: Im not admin of the page https://www.facebook.com/midtfynsgymnasium and i have no problem browsing it, så there must be something wrong at your end.

Comment: Are there any geographic restrictions on this page?  Is it maybe only shown in certain countries?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are attempting to do here?

Comment: Im using the neosmart jquery plugin to get stream from different facebook fan pages. Facebook now require an accesstoken to do that. Im getting the accesstoken by using FaceBook C# from codeplex, authentication using an Facebook App/AppSecret. Using this accesstoken i can get som pages but the pages https://www.facebook.com/midtfynsgymnasium and https://www.facebook.com/Musikogungdomskultur doesnt work. If im authenticate using my personal facebook account it works. But that accesstoken expires so it doesnt work when im having visitors.

Comment: Like I said before - there seems to be some sort of limitations on this page.  Viewing content through the actual Facebook site using your personal user and viewing content through the API are slightly different - it is an issue of privacy.  Are you able to perform these actions on other Facebook pages?

Comment: I can do it on https://www.facebook.com/pages/Midtfyns-Fritidscenter-Ringe/203289513076359 and https://www.facebook.com/pages/Faaborg-Midtfyn-Bibliotekerne/112977092108438

Comment: So as you can see there is a certain limitation on that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook ID is only the last part of your address: https://neosmart-stream.de/facebook/how-to-find-a-facebook-id/

Additionally your access token needs the permission read_stream.